# HTTP connection information in WinInet

Tags: c++, http, connection, wininet

I need to gather information about HTTP connection opening (when did it start, how much time, error codes etc).
I am using the following interfaces in my code:

```
IInternetProtocolSink,  
IServiceProvider,  
IInternetBindInfo,  
IInternetProtocol,  
IInternetProtocolInfo,  
IInternetThreadSwitch,  
IWinInetHttpInfo
```

All these interfaces are from the WinInet SDK (urlmon.h).
My question is: can I use any of these interfaces to gather information about the connection?

Thanks,
Adi Barda

Answer (score 0):

OK. Just got the answer from Igor Tandentnik who wrote the PassThruAPP SDK. you can find it at: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/02ee6346-9bb1-42c6-ab9c-72fdf820027b

Cheers!
Adi